# Confused about overloading resolution of functions in R?

Tags: r

Got confused about which function is called in this case,

```
# Simple linear model
g<-lm(final~midterm, stat500)

# Plot the predicted line, with slope and intercept
abline(g$coef, lty=5)
```

This snippet is taken from http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf, page 15.
The confusing part is calling of abline. The manual says the call signature is

Usage:

```
 abline(a = NULL, b = NULL, h = NULL, v = NULL, reg = NULL,
        coef = NULL, untf = FALSE, ...)
```

and typical usages are:

```
 abline(a, b, untf = FALSE, ...)
 abline(h =, untf = FALSE, ...)
 abline(v =, untf = FALSE, ...)
 abline(coef =, untf = FALSE, ...)
 abline(reg =, untf = FALSE, ...)
```

So how does R resolve that `abline(coef)` is the one that should be called? Coming from python world, it seems that by supplying a single argument without name, the first version should be used, i.e. `abline(a=g$coef, b=NULL)`.

Could someone point out a good tutorial on resolution rule in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `?abline` help page.

> The first form [ `abline(a, b, untf = FALSE, ...)` ] specifies the line in intercept/slope form (alternatively `a` can be specified on its own and is taken to contain the slope and intercept in vector form).

So since you are doing a simple linear regression, `g$coef` is a vector of length two so the values are used as the slope and the intercept.

So really there is no differnce between

```
abline(a, b, untf = FALSE, ...)
```

and

```
abline(coef =, untf = FALSE, ...)
```

The latter just happens to have a more explicit parameter name should you want to use that. You can easily read the source of `abline` if you just type `abline` without the parenthesis. There is only one `abline` function (it's not even generic)